# Why does Hahn-Banach Theorem imply the existence of enough continuous linear functionals to separate points?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Background:

[image]

[image]

Then Folland's real analysis (pg. 167) writes

[image]

May I ask:

1. In proposition 5.15, we only require $q_{\beta}(Tx) \leq C\sum_1^k p_{a_j}(x)$ to hold for one $x$ rather than for any $x\in\mathcal{X}$, right?
2. Why is highlighted part true? i.e., How does Hahn-Banach Theorem imply the existence of enough continuous linear functionals to separate points?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For Proposition $5.15$, it reads more like it needs to be true for all $x$, otherwise $x$ would have been introduced and fixed.

Comment: The first part of the answer in [Proof of Hahn Banach Theorem corollary: the dual of a LCS sperates points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3345806) might help for your second question.